# Setting Mappers of desired numbers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mappers

I have gone through lot of blogs on stackoverflow and also apache wiki for getting to know the way the mappers are set in Hadoop. I also went through [[hadoop - how total mappers are determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195708/hadoop-how-total-mappers-are-determined]) [this] post.
Some say its based on InputFormat and some posts say its based on the number of blocks the input file id split into.

Some how I am confused by the default setting.

When I run a wordcount example I see the mappers are low as 2. What is really happening in the setting ? Also this post [http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/QuasiMonteCarlo.java] [example program]. Here they set the mappers based on user input. How can one manually  do this setting ?

I would really appreciate for some help and understanding of how mappers work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the java system properties `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size` to guide Hadoop to use the split size you want.  This won't always work - particularly when your data is in a compression format that is not splittable (e.g. gz, but bzip2 is splittable).

So if you want more mappers, use a smaller split size. Simple!

(Updated as requested) Now this won't work for many small files, in particular you'll end up with more mappers than you want.  For this situation use `CombineFileInputFormat` ... in Scalding this SO explains: [Create Scalding Source like TextLine that combines multiple files into single mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917404/create-scalding-source-like-textline-that-combines-multiple-files-into-single-ma)

Comment: Hello @Sam: Thanks for your answer. I get your point on deciding the number of mappers based on mapred.min.split.size , but my input-size are so small, that this method doesn't really help. I found a way around, where one can decide based on InputFormat , where one can set it more flexibly [example](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/12/20/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-2-getting-started-with-customized-partitioning/). Thanks